# How do disable asserts in Android debug builds

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In Android Gradle Plugin version 4.1.0 they changed so assertions now always throw in debug builds.
How to disable this feature?

> **Assertions in debug builds**
>
> When you build the debug version of your app using Android Gradle plugin 4.1.0 and higher, the built-in compiler (D8) will rewrite your app's code to enable assertions at compile time, so you always have assertion checks active.

[AGP Release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#4.1-debug-assertions)

Comment: did u find a way?

Comment: Unfortunately no, sorry. It is still an issue for me

Comment: me too.. i changed the code of the library in the end ;(

Comment: Yeah, Jake and Co have been running pretty free and loose with D8/R8 lately.  This is the second breaking change they have done this year.  I'm not sure why they would do this without giving us an option to turn it off.  I assume this is somehow related in an effort to reduce Kotlin bloat.

Answer (score 0):

Work-around:

```java
/**
 * Hack to work-around D8 change that always enables assertions in Android DEBUG builds.
 * Replace "assert boolean" with
 * "if (test) test(boolean)"
 *
 * In test case set "test = true"
 */
public class D8Hack {
    public static boolean test = false;

    public static void test(boolean b) {
        if (!b) {
            throw new RuntimeException("D8Hack.test() failed!");
        }
    }
}
```

In use:

```java
import static D8Hack.*;
public class SomeClass {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1;
        //assert x==0
        if (test) test(x==0)
    }
}

public class SomeTest {
     static {
         D8Hack.test = true;
     }
     public void test() {
         SomeClass.main(null);
     }
}
```

The "assert" code should be short circuited in Debug and R8 should see that `test` is always false in the Android code and remove it.  Hopefully they can add a flag for those of us who share code between Java and Android.